# Using Dagger Multibinding across Gradle modules

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-injection, guice, dagger

Fellow *Dagger* users...am I trying to do something impossible? Below is a [degraph](https://github.com/schauder/degraph) generated Gradle module view of my app.

[image: modular-android-app]

Imagine my app has a navigation drawer. I want the list items in the drawer to be added based on a collection populated via a multibinding. The contributors to this multibinding are across > 1 Gradle module.
For example, a list item called "Account" is added from the `user` module, a 2nd item called "Terms & Conditions" is added from the `legal` module and a "Search" navigation entry is added from the `search` Gradle module. These modules can be thought of as stand-alone apps that when bundled together form the complete app experience. They are runnable on their own.

The Dagger documentation on this looks like a copy-paste of the Guice but with one big complication. It states;

> "Dagger allows you to bind several objects into a collection even when
>   the objects are bound in different modules using multibindings. "

...but it means Dagger @Modules, right? Is it possible to populate a multibinding across Gradle modules? I've tried something akin to this and it wasn't what I expected (not all contributions were collected);

*Parent app*

```
@Module
abstract class PluginModule {
  @Multibinds @NavigationContribution abstract Set<NavigationEntry> navigables();
}
```

*`legal` Gradle module that contains the Dagger @Module*

```
@Module
class LegalModule {
  @Provides
  @NavigationContribution 
  @IntoSet
  static NavigationEntry provideLegalNavigation() {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

*`user` Gradle module that contains the Dagger @Module*

```
@Module
class AccountModule {
  @Provides
  @NavigationContribution 
  @IntoSet
  static NavigationEntry provideAccountNavigation() {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

Upon running the app only the contributions under the app 'context' are available upon calling;

```
@Inject @NavigationContribution Set<NavigationEntry> navigationEntries();
```

The other contributions can be accessed but 'manually' by getting hold of the `dagger.Component` of the child Gradle module and exposing a method to get the entries back.

This defeats the purpose of the multibinder for my application. Is this possible? If not, why?

*Update: triage with Jeff*

[image]

So, the top-level module annotations look like this;

```
@ApplicationLifecycle
@Component(
    modules = {
        OceanLifeModule.class,
        AddSpotActivityModule.class,
        ModelModule.class,
        PluginModule.class
    },
    dependencies = {
        NavigationComponent.class,
        LegalComponent.class,
        PreferenceComponent.class,
        DomainComponent.class
    }
)
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the additional Dagger modules you've listed are actually installed in your top-level Component?

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you for getting back. So my top-level component installs the ````PluginModule```` along with the modules that provide the contributions (````AccountModule````, ````LegalModule```` etc.). The modules are adjacent to each other if that makes sense? I'll draw a picture and add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jeff-bowman - all I was missing here was the `includes = {}` on the `PluginModule`. A blog post by Zac Sweers on the same topic [here](https://www.zacsweers.dev/catching-up-on-catchup-a-dagger-powered-plugin-system/) pointed me in the right direction.